# Color the group in ggplot violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am new to R programming. 
Stuck while plotting ggplot violin plot.
I wish to give color `blue`, `green` and `red` color to my 3 groups.
Here is my dataframe:

```
> print(employee_withoutEmployeeID[1:5,])
> 
  EnvironmentSatisfaction JobSatisfaction WorkLifeBalance
1                       3               4               2
2                       3               2               4
3                       2               2               1
4                       4               4               3
5                       4               1               3
```

What I am trying is:

```
png(file="answer5.png")
answer5 <- ggplot(stack(employee_withoutEmployeeID), aes(x = ind, y= values) )
answer5 + geom_violin()  + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0000")) + 
  labs(title="Answer 5", 
       subtitle="",
       caption="Answer 5",
       x="Measure",
       y="Rating")  
dev.off()
```

I am getting my violin plot plotted correctly, but there is no color fill. I am not sure, how and where to use `scale_fill_manual`
Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the variable to fill on.  The stack function will add the `ind` column onto your input data.frame, thus I added the `fill=ind` into the aes option.

```
answer5 <- ggplot(stack(employee_withoutEmployeeID), aes(x = ind, y= values, fill=ind) )
answer5 + geom_violin()  + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0000")) + 
   labs(title="Answer 5", 
        subtitle="",
        caption="Answer 5",
        x="Measure",
        y="Rating")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `fill` aestetic needs to be specified in `geom_violin` :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x= Species, y = Sepal.Width) ) +
       geom_violin(aes(fill= Species))  + 
       scale_color_manual(values=c("#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0000")) + 
       labs(title="Answer 5", subtitle="",  caption="Answer 5",
         x="Measure", y="Rating")
```

[image]